# Mistake in applying the conditions of cycle

Tags: r

Sorry in advance for stupid question, but I couldn't find it it the search.

The problem seems simple, but it broke my brain in the end of the work day:

```
x=c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,5,5) 
y=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10) 
z=data.frame(cbind(x,y)) 
a=0 
for (i in z$x){ 
  if(i==2){ 
    z$y="NA" 
    a=a+1 
  } 
}
```

The point is this for must check `z$x` and if `x=2` incert "NA" for the corresponding `z$y`. I got this instead:

```
z  x  y 
1  1 NA 
2  1 NA 
3  1 NA 
4  1 NA 
5  1 NA 
6  1 NA 
7  2 NA 
8  2 NA 
9  5 NA 
10 5 NA
```

Note, that the counter for **a** works properly, because there's really `z$x=2` only twice.

```
a 
[1] 2
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use following.

```
z$y[z$x == 2] <- NA

z
##    x  y
## 1  1  1
## 2  1  2
## 3  1  3
## 4  1  4
## 5  1  5
## 6  1  6
## 7  2 NA
## 8  2 NA
## 9  5  9
## 10 5 10
```

Comment: And if I want to copy corresponding rows in a new data frame?